# Xcode does not recognize a folder I've added from another project

Tags: xcode, file-management

When I am adding a new folder, that i took from another project, to my Xcode project (which has many subfolders and classes in it) it creates this folder with a **gray** color and not the **yellow** one as the rest of my project's folders.

Then when I am trying, from another class in my project to `#import class.h` that is in this folder, I get an error saying Xcode doesn't see it in the project.

> class-name file is not found

I have added the folder using "Add files to project-name".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A gray folder is a reference to a folder on disk, whereas a yellow one is a group representing a collection of files in a project.   For most source code, you'll want to use the yellow kind.     To do this, when you add the files to the project make sure that you use `Create groups for any added folders` as opposed to `Create folder references for any added folders`.